# What does it mean to "Glue the boundary circle of a mobius strip to another circle in a 2:1 covering map"

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

What does it mean to "Glue the boundary circle of a mobius strip to another circle in a 2:1 covering map."?

This wording is confusing to me. Does this mean the preimage of the the circle will be two points on the boundary of the Mobius band? Or, is it implied that wrapping a mobius strip around a circle, the mobius strip goes around the circle twice because a mobius strip's boundary retracts onto it's central circle in a 2:1 fashion.

See why I'm a bit confused?

Comment: It is your second version.

Comment: so, if you wrap the boundary of a mobius strip around a circle in a 1:1 covering map, it is implied that every point on the circle will have a preimage containing two different points on the boundary of the mobius strip?

Comment: Yes that is what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general description, of which your particular problem is a special case.

Given two topological spaces $X,Y$, a subset $A \subset X$ and a function $f : A \to Y$, *gluing $A$ to $Y$ using $f$* means forming the quotient space of the disjoint union $X \coprod Y$ using the equivalence relation generated by $a \sim f(a)$, for all $a \in A$.

The equivalence classes of this equivalence relation can always be explicitly listed, but if $f : A \to Y$ is a surjective 2--1 map then the equivalence classes are particularly easy to list: all singleton sets $\{x\}$ for $x \in X-A$; and all tripleton sets $f^{-1}(y) \cup \{y\}$ for $y \in Y$. (In fact this description holds in general except that the sets $f^{-1}(y) \cup \{y\}$ need not always be three point sets).

Comment: Thank you very much for this, just what I needed. I think the way hatcher describes the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, this information about the gluing does not get utilized, because the morphism in the sequence from $H_i(A \cap B) \rightarrow H_i(A) \oplus H_i(B)$ is just basically inclusion. Is there way to modify this in a natural way so information about the gluing, in particular that it is a 2:1 gluing, is reflected in some sort of L.E.S.? Would CW-Homology work better?

Comment: Presumably the way that the gluing gets utilized is something like this. Starting from the definitions of $A,B$ in the quotient space, each of $A$, $B$ and $A \cap B$ can be pulled back to the disjoint union $X \coprod Y$, and thereby each can be described as a quotient. This probably aids in the computation of $H_i(A)$, $H_i(B)$, and $H_i(A \cap B)$ and in the description of the various homomorphisms in the long exact sequence.

Comment: However, going into all that in detail would entail another question, since the particular $A$ and $B$ are not mentioned in your current question.

Comment: I'm gluing the boundary a mobius disc to the circle the is the boundary for a torus once we cut out a copy of $D^2$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295154/let-d-be-a-closed-disk-embedded-in-s1-times-s1-then-x-s1-times-s1

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be the Möbius strip and $S$ be its boundary circle we we may assume to be given together with a homeomorphism $h : S \to S^1$. Now let $\mu_2 : S^1 \to S^1, \mu(2)(z) = z^2$ which is the protype of a 2:1 covering map. Then you form the adjunction space
$$X = M \cup_{\mu_2 h} S^1 = (M \sqcup S^1)/\sim$$
where $s \sim \mu_2h(s)$ for all $s \in S$. Then $S^1$ embeds a subspace into $X$ by mapping $z \in S^1$ to $[z] \in X$. In fact each of these points $[z]$ has two preimages in $M$.