# Is there a cleaner way to express the quotient $\frac{\langle(1,0),(0,1)\rangle}{\langle(2,-8)\rangle}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question

Is there a cleaner way to express the quotient $\frac{\langle(1,0),(0,1)\rangle}{\langle(2,-8)\rangle} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}}{\langle(2,-8)\rangle}$?

To give the question some context, this is a presentation I got when trying to calculate a homology group here:

[Gluing two Möbius strips together along their boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297120/gluing-two-m%c3%b6bius-strips-together-along-their-boundary)

Comment: Are you working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a real vector space? Are these abelian groups and you are working in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and these are abelian subgroups? What are you doing?

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't have said $\mathbb{R}^2$ I suppose. This was my final answer in a homology group calculation.

Comment: Well, it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})$, for example via the map $(m, n) + \langle (2, -8) \rangle \mapsto (4m+n, m + 2 \mathbb{Z})$.  Is that something along the lines of what you're asking?

Comment: You might want to look up "Smith normal form" for a general method of finding what a certain finitely generated Abelian group is isomorphic to.  For the special case of modding out $\mathbb{Z}^k$ by a single vector, the Smith normal form calculation reduces to essentially running Euclid's algorithm to find the gcd of the elements of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotient of the group $\mathbb Z^2$ by any infinite cyclic subgroup is isomorphic to the direct sum of $\mathbb Z$ and a finite cyclic group (which might be trivial). The order of the finite cyclic group is simply the greatest common divisor of the two components of the element that generates the kernel, in this case $gcd(2,-8)=2$. So your quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$.